# Disable Edit Mode on TinyMCE Inline Editing

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a somewhat unique problem. I am working on a CMS for websites, and we are attempting to implement Inline Editing on our sites. We want to use TinyMCE's inline editing feature, where you create a div and that div becomes the editor on initialization.

The HTML:

```
<div class="editable-text">
    <p>My editable text here</p>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".editable-text",
        inline: true,
        plugins: ".....",
        toolbar: ".....",
        menubar: false
    });
```

**The Problem**

The problem is, I need to be able to save the page content after a user has edited a page, but Tiny adds in a bunch of extra classes and HTML to my edit area, which I do *not* want to save:

```
<div spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" id="mce_5" class="editable-text mce-content-body" contenteditable="true">
     <p>My editable text here</p>
</div>
<input name="mce_5" type="hidden">
```

I have looked for different solutions on how to "disable" Tiny before saving the content, but the only solutions I have found have been to completely remove the element (in my case, the div with all the content in it that I want to save!). Is there a way to "disable" Tiny (i.e. remove all of the junk it puts in) without also stripping out my content?

Thanks,

Comment: why not create a fresh `div`, then copy the `innerHTML` from the old to the new and save...?

Comment: If it was simpler, I could. But in reality, there could be many, many divs on the page, each with their own editor. You could possibly do that for every single one using javascript, but if anyone knows of a "tiny.disable()" function or something that just reverts the page back to what it was before it was being edited, that would be much better. It might be possible to do something easily in jQuery if there's no other way.